# How 'true' will Fuschia seedlings be?

Tags: seeds

I know that with things that bear fruit (e.g. Apples) a plant grown from the parent plants seed may not bear fruit that are the same as those of the parent, which leads me to ask the question:

I have a planter which had some purchased Fuschias in them last summer (I *think* they're ones with unusually large flowers for what it's worth). As well as the parent plants having survived over winter, there are what appear to be a large number of baby plants which are presumably from seeds set by the parent plants. Are these likely to produce flowers comparable to those of the parent / are they worth keeping?

Answer (score 4):

There is no way of knowing - fuchsias do not come true from seed, although you may get a plant that looks similar to the parent. It's very unusual for there to be so many viable seeds that you've got lots of little fuchsias growing - many of the pods on the plants do not contain viable seeds. Either way, it'll be interesting finding out precisely what you have got growing and whether there are any fuchsias that are worth keeping. You could always remove the seedlings and grow them on separately, till you see whether there's any worth having.